# Проблема при сравнении значений через сниппет IF ModX Revolution

Tags: modx, revo

```
[[!If? 
    &subject=`[[+category]]`
    &operator=`==`
    &operand=`kyxni-klassika-econom`
    &then=`kyxni-klassika`
]]
```

По логике вещей если значение TV поля `[[+category]]` равно "`kyxni-klassika-econom`", должен выводится текст "`kyxni-klassika`". Этого не происходит, причем если поставить

```
&operand=`[[+category]]`
```

все отрабатывает. Подозреваю что проблема в разных типах переменных, но что-то у меня как-то не получается это проверить.

Comment: включите отладку, добавив параметр &debug=` `1` `, что выводит?

Comment: в данном случае можно обойтись и без этого сниппета, использовав модификаторы вывода: [[+category:isequalto=` `kyxni-klassika-econom` `:then=` `kyxni-klassika` `:else=``]]

Comment: Array ( [subject] => kyxni-klassika-econom [operator] => == [operand] => kyxni-klassika-econom [then] => kyxni-klassika [else] => [debug] => 1 ) string(0) "" это debug

Comment: Конструкция которую вы скинули тоже не помогла, сниппет if кстатит отрабатывает на проверку пустоты значения  [[!If? 
           &subject=`[[+category]]`
           &operator=`!empty`
           &then=`<div>[[+category]]</div>`
        ]], то есть он рабочий, сам с собой когда сравнивает тоже все норм, просто нехочет сравнивать со строкой, я вот и подумал что проблема в типах переменных, хотя это очень странно

Comment: Нашел ошибку у себя, все конструкция помогла, спасибо)